# Есть onclick="параметры" для ссылки вида href="javascript:void(0)". Как воспользоваться этими параметрами, чтоб получить подобие ссылки?

Tags: javascript, парсер

В js не разбираюсь. Парсю сайты на python 3 используя lxml

Есть 2 сайта:

1. http://kinoafisha.ua/cinema/kiev/kinodrom (тут код ссылки можно
   поглядеть нажав на время сеанса)
2. http://www.kinodrom.kiev.ua/film/seances (тут код ссылки можно
   поглядеть нажав на “Купить” рядом с сеансом)

Оба сайта запускают одно и то же окно по выбору места. Как я понимаю, киноафиша имеет js ссылку на кинодром. Я хочу узнать, как мне сделать подобное?

Запарсить параметры onclick не проблема. Что мне с этими параметрами потом делать? Как ими воспользоваться? Как открыть “окно” с выбором мест на своем ресурсе, как на сайтах выше? Нужно ли мне на своем ресурсе размещать какой то js по обработке параметров onclick?

Гуглил, толком ничего не могу найти по обработке js ссылок. Встречал в гугле, что в инспекторе браузера можно найти адрес, куда слать запрос. Не могу найти в инспекторе этот адрес.

Если подытожить, то у меня 1 вопрос: Что делать с запарсенными параметрами onclick, чтоб на своем ресурсе открыть всплывающие окна по выбору мест, как на приведенных выше ресурсах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго времени суток.

1) `javascript:void(0)` в `href` нейтрализует поведение ссылки по умолчанию. Т.е. говорит браузеру, что никакого перехода не будет.

2) `ga('send','event','Время сеанса','2show','Superнянь 2');` - это скрипт Google Analytics. Вам это не нужно.

3) `show2_show(28,[['exclusive_show','Superнянь 2'],['provider','10107'],['event_origin','13.12.2015 19:00']]);` - это сама функция, которая вызывает окно выбора мест с определенными параметрами. Сама функция находится в файле `http://kassa.2show.mobi/javascripts/kassa.js`, который подключается в разделе `<head>` тела страницы

Comment: Хочу уточнить. Правильно ли я понял - если я хочу получить такое же всплывающее окно с выбором мест на своем ресурсе, мне в <head> нужно указать данный скрипт "http://kassa.2show.mobi/javascripts/kassa.js" и повесить ссылку на время сеанса с нужными параметрами onclick по примеру, как это устроено на вышеуказанных ресурсах?

Comment: Совершенно верно. Возможно понадобится еще и файл стилей для этого окна.